# Segmentation fault when accessing shared memory in C

Tags: c, memory, struct, shared, mmap

I have 2 programs which need to share memory. Let's call one program A, the other one B.

There is a struct in this format for this purpose:

```
struct town_t {
    int population;
    char * name; 
}
```

In program A, data gets written to shared memory using mmap. This works for program A. (It uses strcpy for the `name`)

Program B's purpose is to simply read the data. This too works with mmap. Accessing the shared memory's `population` field works without any problems. However, accessing the `population` field gives a segmentation fault.

Since I used strcpy, the entire string should be in the shared memory right?

I use the following flags to get the pointer to shared memory, which returns no error.

```
tptr = (struct town_t *) mmap(0, 1024, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0)
```

How could I make it so I can actually read the string (char*) from program B?

Comment: Using `strcpy` has nothing to do with whether the string is in shared memory. What memory does `name` point to and how did you allocate that memory?

Comment: @immibis I am using strcpy to the shared memory pointer. I allocate with char * str = "string".

Comment: So you do `tptr = mmap(...); char *str = "string"; strcpy(tptr->name, str);`?

Comment: @immibis Well that won't work because `tptr->name` has no particular value, so you're passing garbage (likely NULL) to `strcpy`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ***I*** know why it won't work. I asked the asker if that is what the asker has written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in putting a pointer in shared memory. A pointer gives a location inside the address space of a particular process. It would have no meaning to another process with another address space. (With some complicated exceptions such as a pointer to memory allocated before a call to `fork` accessed by related processes running the same executable.)

You can store the string data itself in shared memory if you wish. For example, this will work:

```
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 100

struct town_t
{
    int population;
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
};
```